# Datagridview similar to SQL Server Table designer with combo box and datetime picker

Tags: c#, .net

From long time I've been struck with Datagridview in C#.net. I need a customized datagrid view with combo boxes, text boxes and date time picker controls which will validate on row-leave and cell-leave events.
I'm very much attracted by the Datagrid of SQL Server data entry. Manytimes I tried that but didn't succeed.
Please suggest me if you know any.

Comment: Winforms and c#.net 2.0 or above

Comment: Winforms and c#.net 2.0 or above

Answer (score 0):

if you are using winforms then you can add combobox as columntype

[for further reference]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s.aspx MSDN

[for DateTimePicker see this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GenericDataGridView.aspx)

image showing how to customise a datagridcolumntype is uploaded below

[image: how to customise a datagridcolumntype]

Comment: I need customized datagridview control. If you know any pls let me know.

Comment: I need customized datagridview control. If you know any pls let me know.

Comment: @Nagesh you select the column type in datagridview so that you can  customize a datagridview